# IntelliJ automatically adds -Z unstable-options when Rust tests are run

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I tried to run a simple Rust test in IntelliJ.

The test command IntelliJ uses is:

```
cargo test --color=always --package myproject-rust --lib mycode::tests --no-fail-fast -- --format=json -Z unstable-options --show-output
```

The test failed with the error:

```
error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler
```

It seems IntelliJ automatically added the `-Z unstable-options` in the command.

I triggered the test using the small green play button at the left side of my test function:

[image]

My test runs fine from the command line.

There is no way I can remove the `-Z unstable-options` from the test configuration.

What can I do to remove it?

Comment: I use pycharm-community-edition (also IntelliJ family) with the Rust plugin and never experienced that. How did you trigger the test?

Comment: So what happens, when you click that play button and then in the context menu it opens select "Modify Run Configuration..."?

Comment: @RichardNeumann The tests ran and generated the error above. It automatically generated a test configuration. In the test configuration, there is no way I can remove the -Z option.

Comment: Weird, as I have a text field there to configure the command line arguments used.

Comment: @RichardNeumann What is your test run command? PyCharm must have generated a similar one. Does it have the -Z option?

Comment: Tested in one of my projects: `test --package ansi-color-codec --lib codec::test_foo -- --exact`

Comment: Oh, wait. On Windows I get the same issue as you: The above is the command line configured, but the IDE actually runs: `test --color=always --package ansi-color-codec --lib codec::foo --no-fail-fast -- --format=json --exact -Z unstable-options --show-output`. Looks like a bug.

Comment: There was a breaking change in Rust 1.70, that broke the test experience. Do you have `org.rust.cargo.test.tool.window` enabled in Help | Find Action | Experimental Features enabled? If yes, try to disable it and check if it helps. It could also help to upgrade to the latest plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

> There was a breaking change in Rust 1.70, that broke the test experience. Do you have `org.rust.cargo.test.tool.window` enabled in Help | Find Action | Experimental Features enabled? If yes, try to disable it.

Doing this, and a restart of IntelliJ fixed the issue for me.